# How do you find the filename and path of a running test in Jest

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I am using Jest for testing. How do I access the filename or file path of the current test being run?

I need a conditional statement that runs different lines of code based on whether it is a unit test file or integration test file.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  if (integration_test_file){
    // run this this code 

  } else if (unit_test_file){
    // run this code instead 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

This information is available in Jest environment. This is the case for [custom environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string):

```
const Environment = require('jest-environment-node'); // or jest-environment-jsdom

module.exports = class MyEnvironment extends Environment {
  constructor(config, context) {
    super(config, context);
    this.testPath = context.testPath;
  }

  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    this.global.IS_INTEGRATION = /match integration/.test(this.testPath);
  }
}
```

The environment is instantiated for each test suite, `testPath` contains full path to current test file.

`IS_INTEGRATION` global variable will be available in `setupFilesAfterEnv` and tests themselves. In case the code needs to be evaluated for all tests, it may belong to environment `setup` and `teardown` methods.

Comment: Yes yes yes! Thank you. We just switched from `jasmine` to `jest-circus` and this was the way to go. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can access the name of the file path of the test being ran in jest via its global variables.

the file path can be found under the global variable

```
jasmine.testPath
```

or

```
global.jasmine.testPath
```

this answer only applies if you're using jest with its default test runner "jasmine" or "jasmine2". results will differ based on the test runner you use. see
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testrunner-string

Comment: Note that using the Jasmine API directly isn't supported, as it would break when e.g. switching to [Circus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-circus).

Answer (score -1):

`__dirname` works a treat (ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-script-using-node-js/)